# Reverse button click event with jquery

Tags: jquery, dictionary, button, hide, show

I created a button that allows adding a geojson file to my map once we click on it. However, I would like to be able to have a hide/show option when pressing on the button.
I mean when I click on it I would like my geojson to appear on my map and once a click a second time I would like it to disappear. However until now each time I press my button a new layer is added to the map...

here is the basic code: I tried with toggle() but did not change...

```js
const button_canton = $("#Limite_cantonales").click(function() {
  $.getJSON("canton.geojson", function(data) {
    var limite_canton = L.geoJSON(data, {
      onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<strong>' + feature.properties.NAME);
      }
    }).addTo(myMap);
    $("#button_canton").toggle();

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info" class="info">
  <button id="Limite_CH">Frontières nationales</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To HIDE the button, remove the `$("#")` and just do `button_canton.toggle();`

To TOGGLE the map try this - it only makes the map once

```js
const $myMap = $("#myMap");
$("#Limite_cantonales").click(function() {
  if ($myMap.children()) $myMap.toggle()
  else {
    $.getJSON("canton.geojson", function(data) {
      $myMap.show()
      var limite_canton = L.geoJSON(data, {
        onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup('<strong>' + feature.properties.NAME);
        }
      }).addTo($myMap);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info" class="info">
  <button id="Limite_CH">Frontières nationales</button>
</div>

<div id="myMap" hidden></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, I am not trying to toggle my map but I am trying to toggle a geojson layer that I want to add to ma map on button click. This work fine but the problems is that each time I press on the button a new geojson layer is added and I would

Comment: If you posted a [mcve] I could help you better. In my code, you only create the map ONCE and then show or hide it. That is what you asked for and again asked for in your comment. Since I do not have a [mcve] from you, I only GUESS that I can test the children of the map